# What is wrong with simple calculator program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int calculate ()
{
double a;
double b;
a =(3.0);
b =(5.0);
cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
cout << "* " << fixed << setprecision (1) << b << "\n" << endl;
cout << "------" << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision (2) << a*b << "\n" << endl;
system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
int calculate(int a, int b, int c)
{
double a;
double b;
double c;
a =(7.1);
b =(8.3);
c =(2.2);
cout << "  " << fixed << setprecision (1) << a << "\n" << endl;
cout << "* " << fixed << setprecision (1) << b << "\n" << endl;
cout << "- " << fixed << setprecision (1) << c << "\n" << endl;
cout << "------" << endl;
cout << fixed << setprecision (2) << (a*b)-c << "\n" << endl;
system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

Question: Why do I have to change doubles--->ints? Does anything standout that is wrong?

Here is the output:
1>------ Build started: Project: HW1-2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  HW1-2.cpp
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1-2\hw1-2\hw1-2.cpp(21): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'a'
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1-2\hw1-2\hw1-2.cpp(22): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'b'
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1-2\hw1-2\hw1-2.cpp(23): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'c'
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1-2\hw1-2\hw1-2.cpp(24): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1-2\hw1-2\hw1-2.cpp(25): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\asus\desktop\hw1-2\hw1-2\hw1-2.cpp(26): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Rewrite your Q. What is line 21?? Cloae to downvote.

Comment: This question is mutating into something completely off topic of the original and now a range of answers here are redundant.

Comment: I totally disagree, I have been editing my code with nearly every comment, except for some which I don't understand. honestly

Answer (score 2):

You've got two functions both named `main()`. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but functions must have unique names within a namespace.

You can name your functions whatever you like. `main()` is special, though -- it's the entry point for the program, the one that gets called when the program runs. If you have another function, you'll need to call it yourself from inside `main()` if you want it to be executed:

```
int foo(int c)
{
    return c + 2;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = foo(a);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: -1 because he acknowledges this and he is saying his problem involves the second.

Comment: @rapptz I don't see any such acknowledgement, and what I do see seems to indicate that both are being used together: "First function works fine until I add the second one..."

Comment: @Caleb now that I reread it, I see this is true. However my downvote is locked until you edit.

Comment: Yes, you can name your functions whatever you like. `main()` is special, though -- it's the entry point for the program, the one that gets called when the program runs. If you have another function, you'll need to call it yourself from inside `main()` if you want it to be executed.

Comment: oh ic, ok let me try what you say, thanks! post right back

Comment: maybe it works now but there are some other problems if you see output errors.

Comment: Now you're not calling `happy()` from within `main()`. More generally, we don't have a clear understanding of what your trying to do, or even what problem you're seeing. We're happy to help, but don't make us guess. You're clearly just starting out -- nothing wrong with that, but if you're a student you'll probably learn more quickly and thoroughly if you ask you instructor or TA for some help.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is most likely on this line:

```
(a*b)c
```

What are you trying to accomplish here? Your compiler should complain that there is a missing semicolon. It's not valid c++. You need to specify another operand (+, -, * etc) between `(a*b)` and `c`

Comment: I changed it to what it is supposed to be (a*b)-c, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`(a*b)c` <-- Error

If you want to multiply, it should be `(a*b)*c`

**EDIT -** Seems like you want to do this `(a*b) - c`, which can be written as `a*b - c` as well.

Comment: that meant to be (a*b)-c

Answer (score 0):

I agree with caleb:

you have two `main` functions.
And since your errormessage points to line `21` which coincidently is where a second `definition` of main starts I would say this is the first error. After that you have the multiplication error where you ommitted the operator as stated by others.

[Explanation of the difference of definition and declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Just a style hint:
Personally I find it convenient to write `function(param1, param2, ...)` rather than `function (param1, param2, ...)` (notice the missing space) since there is a difference between `myDefinedSomething` (variableaccess) and `myDefinedSomething()` (functioncall). (You can also access functionspointers, in that case you ommit the paranthese but you will have a bit to tlearn before you should care about that).

And as stated in the comments, try indenting your code it makes it more readable, consider:

```
for(int i=1,i<10; i++){
if(i%3) {
if(flag){
cout<<"a";
}else{
cout<<"b";
}
}
```

versus

```
for(int i=1,i<10; i++){
    if(i%3) {
        if(flag){
            cout<<"a";
        }else{
            cout<<"b";
        }
}
```

In which one did you notice the missing `}` first?

Comment: Oh ic, what should I replace it with then? what should I call the second "main function"?

Comment: @JustinChiang Name your functions anything reasonable (the name should be short and describe what they do, e.g. `multiplication` if you have a function which takes care of the multiplication expressions of your calculator). Be wary though, do not use names twice. And `main` is a special name in c++, it indicates the starting point of your program

Comment: your wisdom is beyond my understanding, I have copy and pasted it into notebook for future learning. Am I missing curly braces? Oh ic I understand most of what you have written EXCEPT your coding example lol!

Comment: @JustinChiang: I added a link for the difference between declaration and definition (you WILL need the declarations sooner or later). I am sorry if I can't express it in a manner that comes easy to you. If you could point out the spots you have trouble understanding and why (vacabulary, wording, "What is ...") I will edit my awnser to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Like Caleb said, you have two `main()` declarations. The code without the second main function compiles just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    a = (7.1);
    b = (8.3);
    c = (2.2);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  " << a << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "* " << b << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "- " << c << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << (a * b) - c << "\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you wanted this to be a separate function, you could rename it to something else such as `int calculator()`.

Comment: oh ok thank you very much! I'm trying right now!